# PHP hash function doing something strange with "\v" - how do I enable escaping from the command line?

Tags: php, bash, hash, escaping, sha

If I run the following in PHP

`<?=hash('sha256', "\v");?>`

I get this hash:

**e7cf46a078fed4fafd0b5e3aff144802b853f8ae459a4f0c14add3314b7cc3a6**

However if I put `\v` into any of the online tools like http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator, I get the following hash:

**1b5cec8c46451b5375ea7e61f310fe831ad17f62098beb7a5bfce304821e3f78**

---

I realise that PHP is obviously hashing the escaped value, rather than the actual string,

> **\v**    vertical tab (VT or 0x0B (11) in ASCII) (since PHP 5.2.5)

(Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

but what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the same result as the PHP function using the command line or one of the online tools - I've tried `VT`, `vt`, `0x0B` and `11` - but none of them give me the same result.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE: As @Alex-Info.net pointed out, changing the double quotes to single quotes will treat the `\v` as a string, but unfortunately I can't change the PHP in this instance.**

Comment: Why not just change your quotes in PHP rather than try to find how to get escaping work with tools you don'T have control over ?

Comment: @Alex-Info.net yes single quotes will do it. Don't you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, I'd favor chaing your PHP code to match the online/commandline apps. Single quotes will not escape, and gets the results you mentionned.

```php
<?= hash('sha256', '\v'); ?>
```

EDIT: Since you can't change the PHP code, here's how to tweak the command line so that it escapes correctly like PHP does:

`echo -e -n "\v" | openssl dgst -sha256` , -e enables escaping.

Comment: Thanks @Alex-Info.net for your suggestion, I am aware that the single quotes will treat it as a string, but unfortunately I can't change the PHP - It is part of a larger problem where someone has already written the code, and used it to generate hashes in PHP, and now we have to try and verify some of these hashes using the command line.

Comment: Can you clarify "trough the command line" ? Which app/language does the verification ?

Comment: I'm just using the OSX terminal with the following command: `echo -n "\v" | openssl dgst -sha256`. I also verified the results by using some of the online hash generators.

Comment: Try `echo -e -n "\v" | openssl dgst -sha256` , `-e` enables escaping.

Comment: Thanks @Alex-Info.net - that works great! would you like to add that to your answer above, and I'll mark it as the accepted answer?